Give an example of a non-$T_2$ space where the intersection of all open neighborhoods of a point is always a singleton.
I was given this question: Give an example of a space that shows that "if the intersection of all open subsets $X$ containing $x$ os the singleton set $\{x\}$, then $X$ need not be Hausdorff".
My solution was simply the Sierpińsky space. However, I have a doubt with this solution. Say $X = \{0, 1\}$ and the topology be $\mathcal{T} = \{X, \emptyset, \{0\}\}$. We have that the intersection between $X$ and $\{0\}$ is the singleton set $\{0\}$. My doubt stems from the following. Is the intersection of all open sets containing $1$ the set $X$? If so, my example would not be valid. I am not too sure if that is tru, however. Don't operators like union and intersection require at least two sets?
Any feedback is appreciated!

Why do you think it does? Intersection and union of sets are another sets. Intersection and union of just one set are defined (what is more you can define intersection and union of no sets) and coincides with the original set. Even if you needed 2 sets, you could intersect $X$ with itself, couldn't you?

@ClearlyIncompetentGuy Well, intersection of zero sets is tricky in general unless you have some "top set" in the background that everything should be a subset of -- which is the case here considering intersections of subsets of $X$.

@DanielSchepler yes, I meant that in a topological context

And also, in this particular case, intersection of zero sets is ruled out because $X$ itself is always an open subset of $X$ containing $x$.

I am not saying that intersection of zero sets is needed here, just pointing out that this is something we could do if we really wanted to.

It's not clear if your $x$ is supposed to be "for all" or "for one."

Let $X$ be a topological space.
$X$ is $T_1$ if given two distinct points $x$ and $y$, there exist $A$ and $B$ open sets such that $x \in A, y \notin A$ and $x \notin B, y \in B$.
A space $X$ is $T_1$ if and only if each point of $X$ is the intersection of its neighborhoods.
Proof:
Let $X$ be a non-empty $T_1$ space, and let $x$ be a point of $X$. Suppose that $|X| > 1$. Let $y$ be a point of $X$ distinct to $x$. As $X$ is $T_1$, there exists an open set of $X$ containing $x$ and excluding $y$. Therefore, $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all the neighborhoods of $x$.
Let $X$ be a space verifying that each point is the intersection of its neighborhoods. Suppose that $|X| > 1$. Let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct points of $X$. By hypothesis, $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all the neighborhoods of $x$. Hence there exists an open set containing $x$ and excluding $y$. Analogously, there exists an open set containing $y$ and excluding $x$. Therefore, $X$ is $T_1$.

Your example fails to be $T_1$, as every non-empty open set contains $0$. Indeed, the only neighborhood of $1$ is $X$, so $X$ is the intersection of all the neighborhoods of $1$. The intersection and the union of a single set is defined, which is the set itself. Try to think of a space that is $T_1$ and not $T_2$.

An example of a $T_1$ space that isn't $T_2$:

 Let $X$ be an infinite set. Consider the cofinite topology on $X$ ($\tau = \{A \subseteq X : X \setminus A \text{ is finite } \} \cup \{ \emptyset \}$).


 Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points of $X$. The open sets $A = X\setminus\{y\}$ and $B = X\setminus\{x\}$ verify that $x \in A, y \notin A$ and $x \notin B, y \in B$. Hence, $X$ is $T_1$.


 Suppose that there exist $A$ and $B$ open sets such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Then $X = X \setminus (A \cap B) = (X \setminus A) \cup (X \setminus B)$. This is a contradiction as $X$ is infinite, and both $X \setminus A$ and $X \setminus B$ are finite. Hence, $X$ isn't $T_2$ (Hausdorff).


 Note/exercise: a space is $T_1$ iff each point is closed, i.e., a space is $T_1$ iff it is finer than the cofinite topology defined on the same set.


The property "the intersection of all open neighborhoods of each point is a singleton" is known as $T_1$, which is implied by $T_2$ but is not equivalent.
π-Base, Search for T_1+~$T_2$ gives 23 examples of such spaces today. I'd say the classic counterexample would be the cofinite topology on your favorite infinite set (maybe $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb R$), where nonempty open sets are any set whose complement is finite. Then $T_2$ fails because every pair of nonempty open sets must intersect, but every point $x$ has a neighborhood $X\setminus\{y\}$ missing every other point $y$, showing the intersection of all open neighborhoods of $x$ is $\{x\}$.
